# Service nginx can not run

Tags: nginx, service, mkdir

It's very strange that the nginx service start failed but nginx process can run.
I've read many answers about it but no one can solve my problem.

> Mar 10 09:42:50 user systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user nginx[6750]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user nginx[6750]: nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/tmp/nginx/client_body" failed (2: No such file or directory)
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user nginx[6750]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
>
> Mar 10 09:42:50 user systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.

Folder in /var/tmp/nginx:

> drwxrwxr-x   7 root  root 4.0K Feb 10 16:30 .
>
> drwxrwxrwt.  6 root  root 4.0K Mar 10 09:42 ..
>
> drwx------   2 nginx root 4.0K Mar 10 10:15 client_body
>
> drwx------   2 nginx root 4.0K Feb 10 16:30 fastcgi
>
> drwx------  12 nginx root 4.0K Jun  5  2017 proxy
>
> drwx------   2 nginx root 4.0K Feb 10 16:30 scgi
>
> drwx------   2 nginx root 4.0K Feb 10 16:30 uwsgi

I'm running as root and nginx is running as nginx:

> user nginx;

I have to start nginx manually and it works:

> root       947     1  0 Mar05 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
>
> nginx      949   947  0 Mar05 ?        00:02:29 nginx: worker process
>
> nginx      950   947  0 Mar05 ?        00:02:27 nginx: worker process

I can't see any problem. Any suggestion is very appreciated.
By the way, it's not run in docker.

Answer (score 0):

Sovled by simply update nginx from 1.10 to 1.16.
Everyone who has the same problem can try it.